# Supervised Classification Plugin QGIS: change input image; use another raster layer

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, classification, ndvi

I'm doing supervised classification on a sugar cane field for identifying vegetation, soil, and soil and litter.

The plugin is only taking in the GeoTiff taken from the multispectral camera we used (RedEdge, MicaSense) for creation of ROIs and the training shapefile. However, this is not the best input I can use because parts of the field have plenty of shadows from adjacent trees. Thus, the shade throws off my ROIs and my classification.

I have a drastically better view of vegetative biomass if I use the raster calculator to display NDVI ((Band 5 - Band 3)/ (Band 5 + 3)). And would greatly improve my classification process if I could use that raster layer instead of the original GeoTiff raster layer. Alas, the SC-Plugin will only let me use the GeoTiff for the classification process.

I imagine the plugin only takes in <.tif> files. My NDVI is <.tif.aux.xml> so I tried *saving it as* a Tif file. However, QGIS returned an error message saying that my raster layer (a .tif file) was not a supported data source.

How can I get the Supervised Classfication Plugin to accept my NDVI raster layer?